# Calculate the range of the following function in a rigor way $f(x) = \arccos \frac {2x}{1+ x^2}$? without using continuity of $\arccos x$ function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I calculate the range of the following function in a rigor way $f(x) = \arccos \frac {2x}{1+ x^2}$? without using continuity of $\arccos x$ function?

I know that the domain of the given function is $R$, and I know that the range in general of $\arccos x$ function is $[0, \pi]$, but how can I use this piece of information?

Comment: $$\arccos\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

WLOG $\arctan x=y\implies x=\tan y,-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2$

$$\arcsin\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=\arcsin(\sin2y)=\begin{cases}2y &\mbox{if }-\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2 \\
\pi-2y & \mbox{if }-\dfrac\pi2\le\pi-2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff2y\ge\dfrac\pi2\\-\pi-2y & \mbox{if } 2y\le-\dfrac\pi2\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 2):

What you need is computing first the range of
$$
g(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$$
Consider the equation
$$
\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=y
$$
which becomes $yx^2-2x+y=0$. This has solutions when the discriminant is $\ge0$, which means $1-y^2\ge0$, so $-1\le y\le1$.

Thus $g$ takes on *all* values in $[-1,1]$. Can you finish?

Comment: Then since $\arccos x$ is 1-1 and onto so its range is $[0, \pi]$ .... is this completion correct? or you mean another thing?

Comment: @Happy Yes, that's correct, because $\arccos$ is bijective from $[-1,1]$ onto $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: "This has solutions when the discriminant is ≥0" what do you mean by this statement?

Comment: @Happy It's a quadratic equation in $x$, and the discriminant is $b^2-4ac=2^2-4y\cdot y=4(1-y^2)$.